# PostgreSQL "Database cluster initialisation failed"

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-11

I got the error in question on my Windows11 for Postgres-V-12.
The followed the below steps suggested by ASL:

```
initdb -D "D:\PostgreSql\12\data" -U postgres

pg_ctl start -D "D:\PostgreSql\12\data"
```

Now after the last step I am getting an error message;
It says:

```
waiting for server to start....
postgres: could not find the database system 
Expected to find it in the directory "D:/postgresqldata", but could not open file "D:/postgresqldata/global/pg_control": No such file or directory 
stopped waiting 
pg_ctl: could not start server.
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the service `postgresql` status in windows services.

Ensure it is running.

Comment: It's running, but still getting the error in the title

Comment: Ensure the availability of "D:\postgresqldata"  folder first . Run the command pg_ctl -D "D:\postgresqldata" initdb and post the output please.

Comment: "D:/postgresqldata" is the data directory I selected while installing postgres

Comment: This is the output after running above command:                                                    
Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory D:/postgresqldata ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default time zone ... Asia/Calcutta
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... pg_ctl: database system initialization failed