# POSTGRESQL 16 - Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-15, postgresql-16

Hello i am 2 days stuck trying to install POSTGRE SQL. Today it is on version 16 but already attempted versions 14, 13, 15....

It looks like the bin\data folder, which is the db cluster folder, has some kind of structure and on the end of installation i get a POP UP , indicating that the folder setup for the db clusters was not configured right.

I am installing this because i need to run a django project.

This log i got from C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\installation_summary.log:

> Processados com sucesso 1 arquivos; falha no processamento de 0
> arquivos
>
> Called IsVistaOrNewer()... 'winmgmts' object initialized...
> Version:10. MajorVersion:10 Granting full access to Administrators on
> (C:\PostgreSQL\data)
>
> Executing batch file 'rad30F8E.bat'... arquivo processado:
> C:\PostgreSQL\data Processados com sucesso 1 arquivos; falha no
> processamento de 0 arquivos
>
> Executing batch file 'rad30F8E.bat'... processo filho terminou com
> c¢digo de sa¡da 1 initdb: erro: O programa "postgres" ‚ requerido pelo
> initdb mas nÆo foi encontrado no mesmo diret¢rio que "C:/Program
> Files/PostgreSQL/16/bin/initdb.exe"
>
> Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
> Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb
>
> Script stderr:  Program ended with an error exit code
>
> Error running C:\WINDOWS\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\16/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT
> AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****"
> "C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_afbe97298d"
> "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16" "C:\PostgreSQL\data" 5432
> "Portuguese,Brazil" 0: Program ended with an error exit code Problem
> running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
> The database cluster initialisation failed. Setting variable whoami
> from C:\WINDOWS\System32\whoami  Script exit code: 0
>
> Script output:  desktop-peu5949\administrador

When it finishes installing i don't get a windows service of the postgreSQL

[image: error]

Attempted:

[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73093946/postgresql-database-cluster-initialisation-failed)

[Solution2](https://help.statlook.com/knowledge-base/problem-running-post-install-step-postgresql-installation)

[Solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61102245/getting-database-cluster-error-while-installing-postgresql-12-on-windows-10)

Comment: There is almost certainly an earlier error if the "postgres" executable can't be found. Or perhaps it is there but you don't have permission to execute it for some reason (which will depend on how your Windows machine is administered)

Comment: What installer do you use?

Comment: I use The normal installer from The oficial website postgre SQL 16 Windows, 86-64x. I am using Windows 10 64 bits. Already tryed changing installer location but Will try more. You think my Windows permissions are messed? @RichardHuxton

Comment: There's no easy way to diagnose Windows permissions problems in a forum @AugustoCamargo - I'm afraid the permissions model there is more complex than a typical unix-derived setup.

Comment: @RichardHuxton, however i had postgreSQL runnning on this machine before.... I uninstalled it and then the problems started showing

Answer (score 1):

After hours of struggle, the following method was the solution for me. I used this link for the solution:

[PostgreSql "running post install step…the Database Cluster Initialisation failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533980/postgresql-running-post-install-step-the-database-cluster-initialisation-failed)

-- to create and run Postgresql database settings after installation :

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\initdb.exe" -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\data" -U postgres --locale="English_United States.1252"

-- to create and run the Postgresql service:

"D:\PostgreSQL\16\bin\pg_ctl.exe" register -N postgresql-x64-16 -D "D:\PostgreSQL\16\bin\data"

*There are a few details that I would like to draw attention to:
My local computer has the settings **Turkish_Turkey.1254.** This is exactly how my previous Postgres installations were configured.*

The problem seems to be related to windows update or EnterpriseDB deployment settings. However, I am not sure which one exactly caused this error.

The two lines above did exactly what I needed when I ran them from the command line (with administrator rights)

Answer (score 0):

After the first installation failed, I tried to install again, but this time I selected "English — United States" as language. And also change data directory to new file "postgres data" on Desktop. It worked. But still had to add paths for psql.